How do I hide this oddly shaped closet?
We bought this house two months ago. The space above the garage was turned into two bedrooms but left partially unfinished. Most of the unfinished work is laziness/quick job-stuff (sunken outlets, no corner pieces on some of the wall joints, crappy paint job, etc) and I can fix that stuff with time and effort and a bit of rolling my eyes.
However, I can't figure out what to do about this closet.
https://imgur.com/a/CFQWbkO
The room this is in is going to be turned into a private yoga studio so I need it to be not hideous. The most obvious answer is to hire a professional, but I don't have the money for that right now (not until I start earning something). I need ideas on how to hide it nicely for now, and an idea of what kind of goal to work toward to finish it later. Help!

I would place a door header just at the top of the low side, if you want a door.  Place drywall on top of the header and paint.

A few options:

Install an angled curtain across the entirety of that wall. First, hang the curtain and then adjust the bottom so that it is parallel to the floor. You can use safety pins and/or fabric tape without sewing.


Header the top of the opening to the lowest point and install a shorter door. You can use a prehung door and cut the casing and door bottom so that it fits the opening. This will require drywall work and trim to complete.

Case out the doorway to match the existing opening. Cut a door to the angles to fit. Trim around the door frame.


